# Read text from a location on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

I am trying to read text from a location on canvas in Android. I draw text at a specific location using drawtext and x, y co-ordinates. Now how can I read the text back from that location? Something like canvas.getText(x, y) etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to store an ArrayList of objects that contain your text and the coordinates. Then when you get the location you want to read from you just look it up in the ArrayList.

Alternatively you could use a double array, and use the x and y coordinates as indices then store the text at that location in the array when you draw it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Here is the whole scenario. I will have some text (in fact just one letter words) put randomly at various locations. When my cursor reaches those locations if there is a text there I need to read it. Cursor will go in one location by next location. Some locations may not have text. Will this suggestion of yours work for this scenario please?

Comment: It can work, you will need to account for inexact locations, you'll want to split the canvas up into a grid and only allow 1 letter per grid. That grid would be a range of x and y coordinates, the top left corner might be from 0-5x and 0-5y. So what you want to do is when you draw the text store it in that grid, then if the cursor falls in the grid it can look up the text (if any) that is stored there. If there is no text at that grid location then that grid is empty.